# Correct place to query MongoDB in Express API server application with testing?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am creating a Node/Express API server to use as a backend for a React single page application. Currently, I am using the MongoDB Node.js driver (not mongoose) to connect to my MongoDB instance.

My question is where is the correct place to store MongoDB queries (insertOne, FindOne, etc...)? I am hoping that someone with experience in a production team can give some insight.

So far I have been given some advice from people with similar experience, but there seems to be quite a lot of contradiction. Here are the two main practices I've seen:

**1. Connect to MongoDB and query inside controller functions.**

I have been told that it is okay to connect and query the database from inside the controller functions. Here is an example of how that would look:

App structure:

```
├── app.js
├── controllers
│   └── users.js
├── db
│   └── mongodb.js
├── routes
│   └── users.js
```

Connect to MonogoDB in several functions inside `/controllers`, reusing the same connection throughout the application as recommended. Here is an example `/controllers/users.js`:

```
import initMongo from '../db/mongodb';

export const registerUser = (req, res) => {
  initMongo().then((db) => {
    // Register User Code Here
  });
};


export const loginUser = (req, res) => {
  initMongo().then((db) => {
    // Login User Code Here
  });
};
```

Here is an example `/db/mongodb.js':

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

let cachedDb = null;

/**
 * @description Initialzies the DB instance.
 *
 * @returns {Promise} A resolved promise with the DB instance.
 */
export default () => {
  if (cachedDb && cachedDb.serverConfig.isConnected()) {
    return Promise.resolve(cachedDb);
  }

  return MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  }).then(client => {
    cachedDb = client.db('databaseName');
    return Promise.resolve(cachedDb);
  });
};
```

The controller functions are then called by specific routes in `/routes/users.js`, like so:

```
router.post('/register', registerUser);
router.post('/login', loginUser);
```

**2. Create a Models folder and store all DB queries there:**

I have also been told to break the DB queries out into a `models` folder and then reference the queries from there in your controllers like so:

App Structure

```
├── app.js
├── controllers
│   └── users.js
├── db
│   └── mongodb.js
├── models
│   └── users.js
├── routes
│   └── users.js
```

Sample `/controllers/users.js` file:

```
import UserModel from '../models/users';

export const registerUser = (req, res) => {
  const user = new UserModel();
  user.createUser(req.body.user);
};
```

Sample `/models/users.js` file:

```
export default function User() {
  this.createUser = (newUser) => {
    // MongoDB insertOne Query
  }
}
```

Is there any benefit to using one of these methods of the other? Is there a recommended way in a multi-person production team? Am I an idiot and should just be using Mongoose?

I would also love to hear opinions on which method would be easier for unit testing with a platform such as Jest.

Comment: I think you have a race condition with "if (...cachedDb.serverConfig.isConnected())", right? I think normal pattern is to cache a promise that returns a db, rather than caching the db itself. (I know that's not what you're asking about, but it's something that jumped out at me)

Comment: Great question. The reason I have that condition is that in a certain scenario, Mongo could return a DB that isn't actually connected which would blow everything up. I am not sure about the exact scenario though (should have commented it *facepalm*). Since it would reuse the same connection (not start another), that should avoid the race condition from my understanding, no?

Comment: I think the more common pattern is to let the MongoClient worry about connects & reconnects & handle emitted errors. With the code as written, if you start up and call that exported db function 100 times before the first connection completes, you'll connect to mongo 100 times (and eventually end up using the last connection as your cached db).

Comment: @willis with AWS Lambda, it saves the state of the application. Therefore if it was to power down for say 60 mins, the MongoDB instance would time out. If I didn't have that check, the program would return the saved DB that is not connected, which would ultimately not work. I do see what you are saying though, I would max the database connections if I were to call the function in a fast successive nature. Any ideas on a solution for that? Here is some more info: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/optimizing-aws-lambda-performance-with-mongodb-atlas-and-nodejs

Comment: @willis since the DB connection function is a promised base function, the second call would not technically run until the first returns a resolved promise with the database, which would stop that problem, no?

Comment: Interesting! I haven't done any work with aws lambda, so I haven't had to worry about that. Would something like http://codepad.org/d1yaQo8w work? I'm not sure what you mean by "promised base function"

Comment: It just means that any code that is dependant on it would not run until it is returned. Being this is an API, I think it would make it hard, if not impossible for the function to be run successively to cause a MongoDB max connections error.  Here is some more info on promises: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises